# How do I make a django project compatible with AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to make a Django project compatible with AWS Beanstalk. 
I dont want this to be like in AWS tutorial, since they use git and need to setup the whole project as they tell.

I just want to know if there is a way of converting an already created Python-Django project to be AWS Beanstalk compatible. I mean, isn't there a standard project layout to download or a plugin or command-line tool that creates the .ebsettings folder for me? I want to convert my project and upload it throw the AWS web gui, dont need all the git stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using git route. You just need to zip your source bundle and upload to the Beanstalk Web Console. The code structure can be kept the way you want.

Key configurations are:
1. WSGIPath : This should point to the .py file which you need to start the app (WSGI app)
2. static: This should point to the path containing the static files

You can add the configurations in the .ebextensions folder, which should at the root of your app zip. You can read more details here: [Customizing and Configuring a Python Container - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_custom_container.html)